# Can i use oyente Tool on windows?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, security, docker, tools

I am currently working with smart contracts. I want to perform security analysis on the smart contracts I developed. I tried using Oyente Tool and Docker in my Windows 10 Home system. But I can only run a sample program with it.

```bash
docker pull luongnguyen/oyente
docker run -i -t luongnguyen/oyente
cd /oyente/oyente
python oyente.py -s greeter.sol
```

These are the commands I executed using PowerShell, and I got the output. But I have no idea how to access my smart contract file in my system or how to access the file I have uploaded on my git hub account.

Could someone please help me? Is there a procedure to run Oyente on Windows? I found Linux and Ubuntu steps but need help finding a procedure for Windows. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

To use Oyente to analyze your smart contracts, you need to mount a volume from your host machine to the Docker container running Oyente. Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Create a directory on your host machine to store your smart contract
   file. For example, create a directory named **mycontracts** in your home
   directory.
2. Copy your smart contract file into the **mycontracts** directory.
3. Open PowerShell or Command Prompt and navigate to the **mycontracts**
   directory.
4. Run the following command to start a Docker container with Oyente:

`docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/contracts luongnguyen/oyente`

This command will mount your host machine's current directory (**mycontracts**) to the **/contracts** directory in the Docker container.

5. Once the container is running, you can use Oyente to analyze your
   smart contract. For example, to analyze a file named **MyContract.sol**,
   run the following command inside the container:

`oyente -s /contracts/MyContract.sol`

Replace **MyContract.sol** with the name of your smart contract file.

Note that the above command assumes that your smart contract file is in the root directory of the **mycontracts** directory. If your smart contract file is in a subdirectory, you must modify the path in the **oyente** command accordingly.

Also, keep in mind that Oyente is an older tool and may not be the most effective or up-to-date tool for the security analysis of smart contracts. You may want to consider using other tools such as [Slither](https://github.com/crytic/slither), [Echidna](https://github.com/crytic/echidna), or [Mythril](https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril) for more comprehensive security analysis.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I did what you told but i am getting oyente: command not found when executing oyente -s /contracts/MyContract.sol after replacing it with my contract file name. Thank you for your tool suggestions too, i will also try using other tools.